# Get Facebook status updates from page WP7

Tags: facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-7.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to make a Windows Phone 7.1 application which needs to show status updates from a specific Facebook page. I can't find any code to do this.
My app is made in XAML and C#

Could anyone help me out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you will need to call Facebook APIs,and for that you will need to integrate facebook to your application [see this post](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application)

Here you need to create app and use that app id with some permissions like user_about_me,read_stream,publish_stream and call their APIs.Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I already have the code to login to Facebook, and retrieve the access token. The link you posted shows code to post to your own wall. What I'm looking for is some code to show status updates from a specific page, and to post something on that page.